# \n not working when creating dynamic .csv file for user download in PHP

Tags: php, csv, line-breaks

I am trying to create a dynamically generated csv file for user download from a piece of html within my application.  Everything works fine except for the \n doesn't seem to be registering in the file that is output.  It is showing up as nothing in the generated file. The lines are not separated.

I have tried entering the echo output manually and still \n does not produce a line break in my output.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with my headers as I am also getting a console notice:

Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv:

```
<?PHP
$tasks = $_GET['text'];

header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='myProject.csv'");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$tasks = str_replace('</br>',"\n",$tasks);

echo $tasks;

exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$tasks = str_replace('</br>',"\n",$tasks);
```

You seem to be mixing `single quotes` and `double quotes`. Is that ok in php? (normally single quotes are used for `char`, like `\n` here).

Also: you might try `"\r\n"`.

Comment: The "\r\n" did exactly what I was looking for.  THANK YOU!!! I was using mixed quotes because my habit is single, but in reading through other people's stakoverflow questions it was suggested to use double quotes around the \n.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out! (and if this solved you problem, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer :)